# Trying to launch an intent from a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

I have an android app where a listview displays a few items - 'films', and when you click on an item it gives you the option to delete or update the item. The delete works fine, and when you click update it opens up a new fragment with the details of the film correctly populated in edit text boxes. I'm trying to figure out how to get the update button on this new Fragment to work.

Firstly I have it extending FragmentActivity, so is this an Activity, or a Fragment? Should I be using something else? When I go to add my button on click listener like I did in the previous 'ListFragment' it won't let me call 'getActivity()' or to reference the currently selected item in the list 'getListAdapter()'. What should I be calling here/how do I reference the current Fragment/Activity?

Should I have these outside of the onCreate in a separate method? I know there is a lot of questions here, but I am really trying to understand what exactly is going on. Any help would be really appreciated. Here is what my code looks like for the FragmentActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.film_activity);
    //adds listeners to buttons

    updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    filmTitleView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
    filmDirectorView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView_director);
    filmYearView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView_year);


    //retrieves object from intent sent through from previous activity
    //assigns variables

    Intent intObj = getIntent();
    filmTitle = (String) intObj
            .getSerializableExtra("title");
    filmDirector = (String) intObj
            .getSerializableExtra("director");
    filmYear = (String) intObj
            .getSerializableExtra("year");
    filmID = (Integer) intObj
            .getSerializableExtra("id");

    //Greeting message text set
    filmTitleView.setText(filmTitle);
    filmDirectorView.setText(filmDirector);
    filmYearView.setText(filmYear);
    System.getProperty("line.separator");

    final Film f1 = (Film)(getListAdapter()).getItem(filmID);

    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
            Context context = getActivity();

            FilmStoreOpenHelper helper = new FilmStoreOpenHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            FilmDAO dao = SQLiteFilmDAO.getInstance(db);

            FilmStore fs1 = FilmStore.getInstance(context);
            fs1.addFilm(f1);

            boolean updated = dao.update(f1);

            if (deleted){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ("Film " + f1.getTitle() + " Updated"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.close();
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Updated, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace any calls to `getActivity()` with `this`. A `FragmentActivity` is a special `Activity` from the support package that is designed to be used with Fragments. If you're developing for higher than API 11, you can use a regular `Activity`.